# bash script/method that brings down WM/Xorg when a process is done

Tags: bash, shell

I'm attempting to make a Linux system that is meant to run a GUI on top of a window manager, as it requires it for inputs from a device to work. I say attempting because I've been trying for several days but I can't get the bash scripting to work no matter what.

My approach is using a bash script that starts an X session using openbox with nothing on it except for the program I want running on top (I don't care which WM, as long as it's a WM that makes the input work, which I've found that both XFWM4 and Openbox do. I'm willing to use any other that will be better if after testing suggestions those also happen to work). 
Once the program is closed (by selecting Quit on it) I'm left with the WM still running, which I don't want, it must go down along with the app, so the system returns to lightdm's login screen.

I can't modify what the quit command on it does either; would take a long time recompiling and modifying such a big app for something so trivial. This is why I really need the WM to go down by itself when the app's process is gone.

I've tried using the openbox autostart script and also a custom script that is run using the .desktop file that is found by lightdm. All my attempts end up with a script that simply kills the display right after entering the session.

I just want something simple like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
openbox &
guiapp; openbox --exit (or killall Xorg whatever)
```

But this syntax won't work. I've tried using things like `pid=$(pgrep guiapp)` to make it look for the PID every bunch of seconds and if it's not there, kill the WM or Xorg entirely; but those also didn't work, I don't know if my attempts were bad or what. Sorry I can't put those examples since I didn't make backups of my script attempts and I've been trying for quite a long time without success.

I really hope someone can help me.

Comment: `openbox & pid=$!` now you can kill the PID with `kill "$pid"`  does that help?

Comment: I've attempted it like this:

`openbox-session & pid=$!
gnome-terminal --full-screen -e guiapp; kill "$pid"`
(app needs to run within terminal)
sadly it produced the same result I said in the OP; it just kills the Xsession immediately.

Comment: last try, add a `;` after the pid assignment, `& pid=$! ; ...`   thats all what I can help you with...

Comment: also didn't work, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working! I found a post online that was attempting a similar thing to mine and he did this approach:

in ~/.config/openbox/autostart:

```
xsetroot -solid black &
gnome-terminal --full-screen --hide-menubar -e guiapp &
/etc/guiapp/Exit.sh &
```

in /usr/share/xsessions/gui.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenBox Session
Exec=openbox-session
TryExec=openbox-session
```

Finally the actual solution in /etc/guiapp/Exit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

until [[ $(pidof guiapp) ]] ; do
        sleep 1
done

while [[ $(pidof guiapp) ]] ; do
        sleep 1
done

openbox --exit
```

His task was slightly different but all it took was some slight modification of his exit script to tailor it to what I wanted.

This way, LightDM will run OpenBox with the flag telling it to read the autostart script, and autostart will run both the app and a script that will keep looking for the pid of my app every second, and when it's down, it'll quit OpenBox to the login screen automatically, so I can switch to a different DM. Just how I wanted it!